# OneDrive Copy Item using Microsoft Graph SDK - GatewayTimeout at 10 seconds if ~>38mb file

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I am using the MS Graph .net SDK.  Attempting to copy a sharepoint document library to another sharepoint document library.

If the file is approximately 38mb, a GatewayTimeout exception is thrown for an unknown error.

Either MS has a bug, or I am doing something incorrectly.  Here is my code:

```
HttpRequestMessage hrm = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, request.RequestUrl);
hrm.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request.RequestBody), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
await client.AuthenticationProvider.AuthenticateRequestAsync(hrm);

HttpResponseMessage response = await client.HttpProvider.SendAsync(hrm);
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
     var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}

}
catch (Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException ex)
{
     throw new Exception("Unknown Error");
}
```

Anyone see a problem here?

EDIT: Here is my revised code

```
public static async Task copyFile(Microsoft.Graph.GraphServiceClient client, string SourceDriveId, string SourceItemId, string DestinationDriveId, string DestinationFolderId, string FileName)
{
    try
    {
        var destRef = new Microsoft.Graph.ItemReference()
        {
            DriveId = DestinationDriveId,
            Id = DestinationFolderId
        };
        await client.Drives[SourceDriveId].Items[SourceItemId].Copy(null, destRef).Request().PostAsync();
        //await client.Drives[SourceDriveId].Root.ItemWithPath(itemFileName).Copy(parentReference: dest).Request().PostAsync();
    }
    catch (Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

The above revised code continues to give the same error; however, tonight, it is also occurring on a 13.8mb file that previously had worked fine.

Logically, because the error doesn't occur for smaller files, I think it has something to do with file size.

The response is supposed to be a 202 with location header.  See [Copy Item in Graph Docs](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/driveitem_copy); however, I have never been able to obtain a location header.  I suspect that Microsoft Graph is not getting the location header information from the OneDrive API and is therefore throwing a Gateway Timeout error.

Comment: Api works fine for both large and small file, but method returns 504 gateway time for large files,

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you're looking for:

```cs
await graphClient.Drives["sourceDriveId"]
    .Items["sourceItemId"]
    .Copy(null, new ItemReference()
    {
        DriveId = "destinationDriveId",
            Id = "destinationFolderId"
    })
    .Request()
    .PostAsync();
```

This will take a given `DriveItem` and copy it to a folder in another `Drive`.

Comment: Marc,  my code and your code both result in a gateway time out error.   I suspect this means Microsoft has a bug in its api.

Comment: Marc, to add further clarification, I agree that your code should work.  In fact you code and mine are identical with the exception of the send itself since I use the sdk to obtain the URL and item reference.

Comment: Can you post the full error? I'm not able to replicate an error with the code above.

Comment: So I used your code exactly as written above.  It works for some files and not others.  Tonight it is also failing on a 14mb file that had worked on Friday.  The end result when it fails is always the same:

Message: "Code: UnknownError\r\n\r\nInner error\r\n"
Inner Exception: null
StatusCode: System.Net.HttpStatusCode.GatewayTimeout

Comment: For clarification:  I am doing a cross site collection copy from SharePoint to SharePoint.

Comment: Are both sites on the same SharePoint Online tenant?

Comment: For my issue I'm coping file from group drive to users drive on tenant(same tenant)
For small files it works fine, An for large files it also works fine but api call call fails with 504 gateway timeout and file gets copied.

I think copy file operation is not asynchronous as advertised, and load balancer/proxy returns on timeout

Comment: Marc and I had an offline conversation regarding the issue and it does appear to be a bug.  In my case, it was the same tenant and my issue is the same as @AbdulKareem.  It appears that the asynchronous copy feature is never triggering leaving the client to timeout with a 504 error.

Comment: Any updates on the status of this bug? Is it fixed or still a valid issue?