# one drive copy method between two different drives fails with 504 gateway timeout with large files > 10MB

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

[Copy Item](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/driveitem_copy) method fails with 504 gateway timeout when file is copied from group drive to user's personal drive with large file.

Method works fine when file size is small (tested with 170KB)

[Github Issue](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/1777)

Edit:one more thing file actually gets copied but `copy`
 method fails with 504

Comment: Note to down voters, Question contains all relevant information regarding issue, Blame Microsoft for using stack overflow as bug tracker

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46480494/onedrive-copy-item-using-microsoft-graph-sdk-gatewaytimeout-at-10-seconds-if.

Comment: @marclafleur i think you are right but I'm using onedrive instead of SharePoint and file actually gets copied but method fails with gateway time out